# Functioned called from another script returning results twice?

Tags: python

Can anyone tell my why the below is printing `a` and `b` twice to the log?

**Main Script:**

```
from subscript import mytest

a = 1
b = 2

mytest()
```

**Sub Script:**

```
def mytest():

    from mainscript import a, b

    print a
    print b
```

The logical approach here is:

1. Import the subscript into the mainscript.
2. Declare A and B in `Main Script`.
3. Call the function `mytest()`.
4. Print A and B to log.

This is printing A and B twice to the log, rather than once. Can anyone tell me why that is?

Thanks

Comment: How are you calling the script? What's the output?

Comment: hitting F5 in IDLE to run mainscript. output is 1212 instead of 12.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are defining circular imports (the main script imports the subscript, and vice versa). The correct way to handle this would be to pass `a` and `b` as arguments to the `mytest()` function, so the sub script doesn't need to import the main script. So you'd have as your main scipr

```
from subscript import mytest
a = 1
b = 2
mytest(a, b)
```

and your subscript would read

```
def mytest(x, y):
    print x
    print y
```

Comment: Why does it only print `x` and `y` twice?